# how i can access to telegram bot database? I want to edit my bot's database

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new to telegram bots, I want access to my bot users chat_id? is it possible? another way? existence?

I could not find any description about that. How can I obtain it for a user?

Comment: You may find the chat_id of your bot via the telegram cli but I don't know why you should want this.

To obtain the chat_id of an user. The user simply has to contact your bot and in the message you receive from telegram there is the chat_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to store. You can do when an user starts the bot or when he uses some command.

There's no Telegram provided method at the moment.